# RoR - inline query in array transform (collect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm building a summary of data based on multiple entities - to keep things simple for eg.  a list of categories and the number of items present in each category returned as json e.g.

```
{"report":["Fruit",35]}


@array = []
@active_rec = Category.all
@array = @active_rec.collect{ |u| [u.name, ?how to insert AR query result? }
```

How can I plug a value along with the name that is the result of another query eg. is it possible to perform a query inline on a current row ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please specify what you need to do? what does `35` mean? Explain it in words.

Comment: I want to perform a query for each row that is processed in the collect - eg. grab names from the result and for each category do a lookup and count items that have that category. stick it together and return it as json. Fruit is just a category, 35 is the result of some query - its how to combine the data that I'm not sure of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some assumptions about your date model:

```
Fruit.joins(:category).group('categories.id').select('categories.name, COUNT(fruits.id)')
```

Or (depending on how you want to handle the case of duplicate category names):

```
Fruit.joins(:category).group('categories.name').count('fruits.id')
```

Note the output will be in a different format depending on which of these you choose.